# Converting EPS to PDF fails on MacOs with Texlipse

Tags: pdftex, texlive, mac, texlipse, eclipse

On a mac 10.10.5 with texlipse plugin for the IDE Eclipse (newest version MARS) together with TeXLive/TeXShop I am trying to convert a tex-file with an eps image to pdf and I use epstopdf-package for that purpose.

When converting the tex-file log sais that a eps-to-pdf file is generated but not found afterwards, see excerpt from log:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <eijkel2.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 1997-11-28 09:36:34
(epstopdf)                    size: 13532 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <eijkel2-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=eijkel2-eps-converted-to.p
df eijkel2.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 249.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=eijkel2-eps-converted-to.pdf eijkel2.eps)...execu
ted safely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <eijkel2-eps-converted-to.pdf>.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `eijkel2-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Within the tex-file I included:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
Here is the complete tex-file/code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\mailsa}\path|{alfred.hofmann, ursula.barth, ingrid.haas, frank.holzwarth,|
\urldef{\mailsb}\path|anna.kramer, leonie.kunz, christine.reiss, nicole.sator,|
\urldef{\mailsc}\path|erika.siebert-cole, peter.strasser, lncs}@springer.com|    
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}

\begin{document}


% a short form should be given in case it is too long for the running head
\titlerunning{Lecture Notes in Computer Science: Authors' Instructions}

\author{Alfred Hofmann%
\thanks{Please note that the LNCS Editorial assumes that all authors have used
the western naming convention, with given names preceding surnames. This determines
the structure of the names in the running heads and the author index.}%
\and Ursula Barth\and Ingrid Haas\and Frank Holzwarth\and\\
Anna Kramer\and Leonie Kunz\and Christine Rei\ss\and\\
Nicole Sator\and Erika Siebert-Cole\and Peter Stra\ss er}
%
\authorrunning{Lecture Notes in Computer Science: Authors' Instructions}
% (feature abused for this document to repeat the title also on left hand pages)

% the affiliations are given next; don't give your e-mail address
% unless you accept that it will be published
\institute{Springer-Verlag, Computer Science Editorial,\\
Tiergartenstr. 17, 69121 Heidelberg, Germany\\
\mailsa\\
\mailsb\\
\mailsc\\
\url{http://www.springer.com/lncs}}

\toctitle{Lecture Notes in Computer Science}
\tocauthor{Authors' Instructions}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
The abstract should summarize the contents of the paper and should
contain at least 70 and at most 150 words. It should be written using the
\emph{abstract} environment.
\keywords{We would like to encourage you to list your keywords within
the abstract section}
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
TEXT

\subsection{Checking the PDF File}

TEXT
\subsubsection{Lemmas, Propositions, and Theorems.}

TEXT

\subsection{Figures}
TEXT
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6.2cm]{eijkel2} 
\caption{One kernel at $x_s$ (\emph{dotted kernel}) or two kernels at
$x_i$ and $x_j$ (\textit{left and right}) lead to the same summed estimate
at $x_s$. This shows a figure consisting of different types of
lines. Elements of the figure described in the caption should be set in
italics, in parentheses, as shown in this sample caption.}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}


\paragraph{Remark 1.}

TEXT

\subsection{Formulas}

TEXT


\subsection{Footnotes}

TEXT AGAIN

\subsection{Program Code}

Program listings or program commands in the text are normally set in
typewriter font, e.g., CMTT10 or Courier.

\medskip

\noindent
{\it Example of a Computer Program}
\begin{verbatim}
program Inflation (Output)
  {Assuming annual inflation rates of 7%, 8%, and 10%,...
   years};
   const
     MaxYears = 10;
   var
     Year: 0..MaxYears;
     Factor1, Factor2, Factor3: Real;
   begin
     Year := 0;
     Factor1 := 1.0; Factor2 := 1.0; Factor3 := 1.0;
     WriteLn('Year  7% 8% 10%'); WriteLn;
     repeat
       Year := Year + 1;
       Factor1 := Factor1 * 1.07;
       Factor2 := Factor2 * 1.08;
       Factor3 := Factor3 * 1.10;
       WriteLn(Year:5,Factor1:7:3,Factor2:7:3,Factor3:7:3)
     until Year = MaxYears
end.
\end{verbatim}
%
\noindent
{\small (Example from Jensen K., Wirth N. (1991) Pascal user manual and
report. Springer, New York)}

\subsection{Citations}

TEXT

\subsection{Page Numbering and Running Heads}

TEXT

\subsubsection*{Acknowledgments.} The heading should be treated as a
subsubsection heading and should not be assigned a number.

\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem{jour} Smith, T.F., Waterman, M.S.: Identification of Common Molecular
Subsequences. J. Mol. Biol. 147, 195--197 (1981)

\bibitem{lncschap} May, P., Ehrlich, H.C., Steinke, T.: ZIB Structure Prediction Pipeline:
Composing a Complex Biological Workflow through Web Services. In: Nagel,
W.E., Walter, W.V., Lehner, W. (eds.) Euro-Par 2006. LNCS, vol. 4128,
pp. 1148--1158. Springer, Heidelberg (2006)

\bibitem{book} Foster, I., Kesselman, C.: The Grid: Blueprint for a New Computing
Infrastructure. Morgan Kaufmann, San Francisco (1999)

\bibitem{proceeding1} Czajkowski, K., Fitzgerald, S., Foster, I., Kesselman, C.: Grid
Information Services for Distributed Resource Sharing. In: 10th IEEE
International Symposium on High Performance Distributed Computing, pp.
181--184. IEEE Press, New York (2001)

\bibitem{proceeding2} Foster, I., Kesselman, C., Nick, J., Tuecke, S.: The Physiology of the
Grid: an Open Grid Services Architecture for Distributed Systems
Integration. Technical report, Global Grid Forum (2002)

\bibitem{url} National Center for Biotechnology Information, \url{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov}

\end{thebibliography}

\section{Checklist of Items to be Sent to Volume Editors}
Here is a checklist of everything the volume editor requires from you:


\begin{itemize} 
\settowidth{\leftmargin}{{\Large$\square$}}\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
\itemsep8pt\relax
\renewcommand\labelitemi{{\lower1.5pt\hbox{\Large$\square$}}}

\item The final \LaTeX{} source files
\item A final PDF file
\item A copyright form, signed by one author on behalf of all of the
authors of the paper.
\item A readme giving the name and email address of the
corresponding author.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you provide a full code that give this error?

Comment: Thank you for your welcome and answer. I just edited my post revealing the complete tex-code.

Comment: try to reduced the code by making as little as possible (see MWE couldn't link it easily right now)

Comment: What would you have me to show you of the code? I reduced it a bit (especially the text sections).